# How to deal with postbacks from multiple strongly-typed submit-able partial views on one view?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/MasterPage.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<EAZYITT_LOGIN.Models.CombinedViewModel>" %>
 <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    LoginPage
 </asp:Content>         
 <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">         
     <div id="LoginWindow">    
         <% Html.RenderPartial("LoginWindow", ViewData.Model.Logon); %>                 
         <a id="ForgetPassword" href="#" onclick="loadSegment()">Forgot  Password</a>
     </div>         
     <div id="PassReminderWindow">
         <% Html.RenderPartial("ReminderWindow", ViewData.Model.Reminder); %>                 
     </div>
 </asp:Content>
```

Each partial view is strongly typed with separate postbacks to the server

Login:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<EAZYITT_LOGIN.Models.LogOnModel>" %>     
<div id="loginPage">
     <h2>Login Page</h2>     
     <h3>Submit your credentials to continue or register</h3>             

     <%: Html.ActionLink("New Registration", "Register")%>     
     <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
     <%: Html.ValidationSummary()%>     

     <div class="validation-summary-errors">
         <span id="loginError"></span>
     </div>

     <% using (Html.BeginForm("LoginWindow","Account",FormMethod.Post)) { %>

     <%:Html.LabelFor(m =>m.EmailAddress) %>
     <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress) %>
     <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress) %>

     <%:Html.LabelFor(m =>m.Password) %>
     <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) %>
     <%:Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)%>

     <%:Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)%>
     <%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)%>

     <p>
         <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
     </p>

     <% } %>
</div>
```

Password Reminder:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<EAZYITT_LOGIN.Models.ReminderModel>"%>         

     <div id="PasswordReminderDiv">
         <h2>PasswordReminder</h2>

         <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
         <div class="validation-summary-errors"><span
 id="reminderError"></span></div>

         <% using (Html.BeginForm("PasswordReminder",
 "Account",FormMethod.Post))
           { //'8' o-o +:: %>

           <%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ReminderEmailAddress) %>
           <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>
 m.ReminderEmailAddress)%>
           <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReminderEmailAddress) %>

           <p>
             <input type="submit" value="Send Reminder" />
           </p>
         <%} %>
     </div>
```

The results are submitted to their separate methods in the controller:

```
         [HttpGet]
         public ActionResult Login()
         {
             CombinedViewModel cModel = new CombinedViewModel();

             cModel.Logon = new LogOnModel();
             cModel.Reminder = new ReminderModel();

             return View(cModel);
         }

         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Login(CombinedViewModel _login)
         {
             return View(_login);
         }

         [HttpGet]
         public ActionResult LoginWindow()
         {
             return PartialView();
         }

         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult LoginWindow(LogOnModel _login)
         {
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 if (LoginService.ValidateUser(siteId, _login.EmailAddress, _login.Password))
                 {
                     //Goto Next Page
                     ModelState.AddModelError("loginError", "LOGIN - OK");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     //Failed Login
                     ModelState.AddModelError("loginError", "Wrong username or password");
                 }
             }

             return PartialView("LoginWindow", _login);
         }     

         [HttpGet]
         public ActionResult PasswordReminder()
         {
             return View();
         }


         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult PasswordReminder(ReminderModel _reminder)
         {
             TempData["ModelState"] = ModelState;
             if (LoginService.ValidateNewUser(siteId, _reminder.ReminderEmailAddress))
                 ModelState.AddModelError("reminderError", "The E-mail address does not exist");

             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("reminderError", "E-mail found, send e-mail to user");     
             }

             return PartialView("PasswordReminder",_reminder);     
         }
```

Ideally, I would like the main view (Login.aspx) to be displayed regardless of the validation.

However, I've currently got the validation on each partial view working, BUT it is taking me to their separate partial views on failed validation as opposed to the main view.

How would I get it to update the partial view only? Is this the way to do it or should I be using AJAX?

Comment: Check this out, it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838200/mvc-net-multiple-forms-childaction

Comment: Thanks, just took a look at that link.  I've attempted that approach and didn't manage to get it to work.  Will be trying Ajax.BeginForm and will post back if I get anywhere with it.

Comment: AJAX.BeginForm works brilliantly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to update the partial view only is AJAX, use AJAX.BeginForm or use JQuery.  Otherwise, it expects to go through the full lifecycle.

HTH.

Comment: Hey Brian, cheers for the reply.  I'll take a look into it and see.

Comment: It worked Brilliantly! Thanks.  Will also need to add this due to debug errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405966/error-with-ajax-beginform-on-asp-net-mvc-page and replace "if (debug)" with "if(!HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)"